# ¿Error en consultar datos uniendo varias tablas mysql?

Tags: mysql

Desde la tabla `farmacia` se registra la marca o la matriz y desde allí dependerá el resto de sus cadenas es decir sus sucursales, luego se lista el listado de empleados que trabajan en dicha sucursal, luego los medicamentos en que sucursal se encuentra disponibles, luego los medicamentos deberán mostrar los datos tales como el laboratorio de su creación, luego también el detalle de la monodroga en la monodroga también debe coincidir con el laboratorio.

He tratado mediante referencias web pero sale error, este el códgio:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT farmacia.*, sucursales.*, empleados.*, medicamentos.*, monodroga.*, laboratorios*
        FROM farmacia f 
        JOIN sucursales s
            ON s.id_sucursal = f.id_farmacia
        JOIN empleados e
            ON e.trabaja_id_socursal = s.id_sucursal
        JOIN laboratorios l
        JOIN monodroga mo
        JOIN medicamentos m
            ON m.laboratorio_id = l.id_laboratorio, m.monodroga_id = mo.id_monodroga
        LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($datos);

if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $datos;
    }
} else {
    echo "Error!";
}
```

Actualmente esta es mi base de datos, con mis tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y cual es el error? y ese query trae absolutamente todos los campos de todas las tablas? en serio queres mostrar todo eso?

Comment: Hola @gbianchi me muestra este error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\Clases\a.php:31 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Clases\a.php on line 31

Comment: eso, deberia estar en la pregunta.. no? y cual es la linea 31? y esa query anda? puede ser que el prepare halla fallado?

Comment: @gbianchi si, pero con explicarme como obtener un dato por cada tabla unida creo que podría hacer el resto yo sin problemas :) y creo que para ello se tendrá que crear una condición más a la consulta que la farmacia sea el padre principal aplicando la condición WHERE id_farmacia=1

Comment: @gbianchi La línea 31 es $stmt->bind_result($datos);

Comment: pero.. tu pregunta es sobre tu error en php o sobre sql? si es sobre sql, el php no importa... y para sql, solo tenes que aplicar los joins, como corresponde.. probaste ir uniendo de a una tabla para ir obteniendo los valores? y el limit 1, hace que muestres un solo registro...

Comment: @gbianchi en ambos prácticamente pero si es en solo sql no habría inconvenientes yo podría plantear el codigo PHP ahora pues estaría mal el planteamiento sql dado a que muestra un error.

Comment: ok.. entonces transforma la pregunta en una sobre sql.. ejecuta ese codigo y fijate que error tenes en sql.. luego dinos que queres obtener (todos los campos de todas las tablas no es algo que tenga sentido)... muestras que te sale, y muestranos que queres que salga...